# Обращение к элементу массива по индексу

Tags: массивы, android-sdk, android, java

Помогите найти баг. Если выбрать из listView 2 элемента первый и второй то все норм. Если первый и последний, то полчуаю ошибку о том, что вышли из массива. Уменшал крайний массив на 1 все равно такая же ошибка

http://ideone.com/p5F1jh

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     SparseBooleanArray boolCheck=listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            for (int i=0; i<boolCheck.size(); i++){
                if(boolCheck.get(boolCheck.keyAt(i))){
                    MainActivity.items.remove(boolCheck.keyAt(i));
                }
            }
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
            break;
    }
}
```

Есть другой метод типо arrayboolen, чтобы он проверял все весь массив. Прост получается у меня 4 строки и если я выбрал строки с индексом 0 и 3, то но проверяет те, которые были нажаты, а те которые были посередине просто пропадают.

Comment: Такой метод хорош, если нужно выбрать из 5 строк допустим 3 забрать их....но а если нужно выбрать 3 и удалить их..чтобы осталось 2...Дебагом прошелся только прошел в итоге он проверяет как раз таки 2 строки а остальные игнорит.в итоге у меня после выбора 2 строк из 5 пропадают все 5.

Comment: При удалении элемента из списка все следующие за ним сдвигаются на -1 позицию и длинна списка уменьшается - соответственно у Вас только один элемент удаляется правильно, а остальные на момент обращения к ним уже "переехали".     
Что бы этого избежать нужно удалять элементы с конца списка, либо использовать `Iterator`

Comment: удаляются не один а может быть даже 10 одновременно из 100... Короче на картинку гляньте может так понятнее будет?
http://snag.gy/FbV7J.jpg

Comment: @xTIGRx, за один раз удаляется именно один элемент, а следующие за ним сдвигаются на 1 индеус назад. То есть, если вы удаляете элемент под индексом 2, то в следующую итерацию i у вас будет иметь значение 3. И соответственно, вы не проверите элемент, который сдвинулся на индекс 2 после удаления. После удаления нужно дополнительно делать i--;

Comment: тоесть получается что при удалении...массив выходит за границы вперед...тоесть он уже проверят 6 элемент а его нет. правильно я понял вас?

Comment: @metalurgus, гляньте код в начале...насоветовали мне тут. теперь у меня даже первый элемент удалить не могу...

Comment: @xTIGRx да вы что, серьезно? А я и не посмотрел, ай-яй-яй...    
Вы серьезно думаете, что я не посмотрел на ваш огрызок кода? И вы хотите, что бы я, используя свои экстрасенсорные способности определил, в чем же у вас там ошибка?? Извините, но у меня таких нет...

Comment: [xTIGRx][1], Вам пытаются помочь, а Вы ещё и недовольны... Вот Вам решение проще некуда, надеюсь поймёте в чём разница.

    List items = MainActivity.items;
    for (int i = items.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (boolCheck.get(i)) {
   items.remove(i);
  }
 }

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/22339/xtigrx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью for-each.

Comment: @woesss спасибо работает все), только тут -1 ни к чему. items.size() - 1; я так написал items.size();. 

@metalurgus Можно было просто сказать простыми человеческими словами что чтобы избежать проблему нужно удалять элементы не с 0 индекса а с последнего, просто я не понял то что вы мне написали,
"После удаления нужно дополнительно делать i--;"
Я взял и прописал после items.remove(i); i--; так прога у меня вообще полетела.но все равно спасибо.

Comment: @xTIGRx 

>  только тут -1 ни к чему. items.size() - 1; я так написал items.size();        

Заведите себе привычку ВСЕГДА писать правильно - это избавит Вас от многих досадных недоразумений.